# How to tell if you are filled in MQL4 order?

Tags: mql4, forex

I can't for the life of me how to tell if a pending order that has been sent and you have gotten a valid ticket, is filled in MQL4

http://book.mql4.com/trading/index

Is there a callback or, does a script have to continuously poll somehow?

Comment: hi, are you saying that you want to be sure if pending order is closed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

**Neither** the Broker/Terminal ecosystem, nor the **`MQL4`** language provide a callback once a `Pending Order` meets the Market Price and converts into a Trade.

### Yes.

One **may** opt to either poll the `dbPool` of records in MT4/Terminal in a rather dumb manner alike a loop

```
int trades_total = OrdersTotal();

for ( int i = 0; i < trades_total; i++ ) {
      OrderSelect( i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES );
      if (       OrderSymbol() == Symbol()
         && OrderMagicNumber() == Magic
         && (      OrderType() == OP_BUYSTOP
            ||     OrderType() == OP_BUY
            )
         ) { ...
```

or one **may** create / store / maintain one's own **`DMA`**-alike bag ( array ) of record-numbers ( used as somewhat like pointers ) and associated Order attributes, which can mediate both direct access/modification ( without a prior `dbPool` `OrderSelect()` ).

The real-time maintenance an use of such an immense bag-of-records was tested as doable for low intensity HFT with hundreds thousands of active Orders ( which would be impractical to have to get handled via `dbPool` `OrderSelect()/Order*()` instrumentation ( the less in `Strategy Tester` multicriterial optimisation mode ).

Comment: Thanks. What about this "ForexConnect" API? Does that also stink?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the order ticket, then you can periodically check **`OrderType()`**. It will change from *BUY_STOP* ( **`OP_BUYSTOP`** ) to *BUY* ( **`OP_BUY`** ), etc. then you know that your order is filled.

```
int myTicket;

void OnTick()
{
  // check for order filled
  OrderSelect(myTicket, SELECT_BY_TICKET);
  int type = OrderType();
  if((type == OP_BUY) || (type == OP_SELL))
  {
    // order is filled, do something here.
  }
  else
  {
    // order is not filled yet. keep waiting.
  }
}
```